# How to insert duplicate keys using spring data?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities QuoteRequest.java and Quote.java that represent two tables in my database: quotes and quote_requests.

Business logic says that every Quote has a QuoteRequest but only one Quote is the default one so I added a column "default_flag" to the quotes table and created a constraint based on the columns quote_request_id and default_flag.

Every time I try to create a new Quote and make it default, I get this error :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

and further down the stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.quotes' with unique index 'quote_uk2'. The duplicate key value is (2, 1).
```

And here is the code that tries to save the new Quote in the database:

```
@Transactional
public Quote createNewQuote(Long quoteRequestId, SomeForm data) {

    QuoteRequest quoteRequest = quoteRequestRepository.findOne(quoteRequestId);

    Quote quote = new Quote();

    // code that fills the quote with data from SomeForm
    quote.setQuoteRequest(quoteRequest);
    quote.setDefaultFlag(true);


    Quote oldDefaultQuote = quoteRepository.findUniqueByQuoteRequestAndDefaultFlag(quoteRequest, true);

    if (oldDefaultQuote != null) {
        oldDefaultQuote.setDefaultFlag(false);
    }

    quoteRepository.save(oldDefaultQuote);
    quoteRepository.save(quote);

    return quote;
}
```

So how do I create a new row in a table that has a unique constraint ( columns quote_request_id and default_flag) given that the new row has the same unique combination as an already existing record ?

Comment: Remove the call to save(oldDefaultQuote), which is useless, since the quote is attached. Replace it by a call to flush() to make sure the false value is saved first, then save the new quote.

Comment: What do you mean by "the quote is attached" ?

Comment: It's managed by the persistence context. All changes are made persistent automatically. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-managed-state

Comment: And will the @Transactional annotation still protect me in case something goes wrong after the flush() so that I don't get stuck with no default quote ?

Comment: Yes, of course. A flush does not commit. It just tells Hibernate to actually execute the SQL statements that need to be executed to store all the pending changes to the database. Just like if, in JDBC, you executed an insert or an update statements. That does not commit.

Comment: Yes, it sure does. I just tested this and everything works as it should. But why didn't my code work this way ? By the way, my repositories were implementing the CRUDRepository, not JpaRepository.

Comment: Most probably because Hibernate decided to insert the new row before updating the existing one.